# How do I extend own library?

Tags: codeigniter, libraries, extend

I am new in codeigniter and want to add a library to my first ci app which extends another library

```
class Mylib {}
```

/application/libraries/Mynewlib.php:

```
class Mynewlib extends Mylib{}
```

Where do I have to put Mylib.php and how do I load Mylib?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you need to access another library with in library?

Comment: Read the User Guide about creating Libraries. http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/creating_libraries.html

Comment: @Craig: I read this Guide already. But where is explained how to extend OWN library, not NATIVE library?

Comment: @wolfgang1983: Yes of course, thats why I extend Mylib, so I dont need to write the same code in all subclasses of Mylib. ;)

Comment: Have you included lib file before extending it? Or maybe tried with core controllers?

Answer (score 5):

I'm still looking for best pratice in this case.

In my case, I have 2 classes should extend from a parent. 
(Payment - parent class; 
Payment_paypal - interact with Paypal; 
Payment_nganluong - interact with Ngan Luong, my domestic gateway)
With each payment gateway, I have to write some properties, method to process but almost base properties and method of theme are the same.

My solution: I created 4 file:

1. Payment_base.php

   `class Payment_base {
       // base properties and method
   }`
2. Payment.php

   `require_once (APPPATH.'/libraries/Payment_base.php'); 
   // this is an instance of payment_base, 
   // when you want to use base method and properties
   // just call $payment->...
   //
   class Payment extends Payment_base {
       public function __construct(){
           parent::__construct()
       } 
   }`
3. Payment_paypal.php

   `require_once (APPPATH.'/libraries/Payment_base.php');
   class Payment_paypal extends Payment_base{}
   //////////////////////////////////////////
   require_one 'Payment_base.php'; 
   class Payment_paypal extends Payment_base { 
   // properties and method
   }`

4, Payment_nganluong.php

```
require_once (APPPATH.'/libraries/Payment_base.php');
class Payment_nganluong extends Payment_base { 
// properties and method
}
```

That's it, and in controller:

```
$this->load->library('payment');
$this->load->library('payment_paypal');
$this->load->library('payment_nganluong');
$this->payment->myMethod(); // base method
$this->payment_paypal->charge(); // call to paypal to charge money
$this->payment_nganluong->checkout(); // check out with Ngan Luong
// no need to load and use payment_base
```

Hope some helpful for you.

Answer (score 2):

This works for me.

library file Mylib.php

```
class Mylib {
   function test() 
   {
       return 1;
   }
}
```

library file Mynewlib

```
require_once('Mylib.php');   
class Mynewlib extends Mylib{}
```

controller

```
$this->load->library('Mynewlib');
echo $this->Mynewlib->test();
```

Answer (score 0):

you create a file in `application/libraries/mylib.php`

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class MyLib
 {

    function __construct() 
    {
         // initialize variables if you want
    }

    public function  my_function($something)
    {
    $out = $something . " World";
    return $out;
    }

}

/* End of file mylib.php */
```

then in your controller you call your library like this

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
class my_controller extends CI_Controller 
{
    public function index()
    {
        $this->load->library('mylib'); // call the custom class MyLib
        $term = $this->mylib->my_function("Hello");
        echo $term; // Hello World
    }
}
/* End of file my_controller.php */
/* Location: ./application/controllers/my_controller.php */
```

Hope that helps

see http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide2/general/creating_libraries.html for more details

Comment: this answer doesnt match with Glueckstiger's question

Answer (score 0):

You could use get instance in library to load another library in

```
<?php

class MyLib {

public function __construct() {
    $this->CI =& get_instance();
    $this->CI->load->library('mylib2');

}

public function something() {
   $this->CI->mylib2->some_function();
}

}
```